# Динамическое добавление checkbox android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Почему-то добавленный checkbox с помощью этого кода:

```
    RelativeLayout test = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.testRelative);
    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
    checkbox.setText("completed");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams RL = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    test.addView(checkbox, RL);
```

Имеет иной стиль вывода, чем тот, что добавлен в xml файл этого же активити:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
    android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox8" />
```

Отличаются они только фоном. Первый имеет черный фон (тот CheckBox, что задан динамически), второй имеет стандартный синий цвет (CheckBox с XML файла). 
Мне необходимо, чтобы они были в одном стиле, какие поправки нужно внести, чтобы это реализовать?

Comment: Не уверен, но вам нужен другой конструктор который принимает помимо контекста стиль. Но можно попробовать сделать так, создайте леяют который состоит только из чекбокса и инфлетите его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так. Сначала создать layout файл "chbTemplate" с чекбоксом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxMy"
    android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox8" />
```

потом inflate этот layout в ваш CheckBox:

```
CheckBox myChb = (CheckBox)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chbTemplate, null);
```

Надеюсь, что это поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Можете объяснить, почему у меня возникла эта проблема? Такая же проблема с radiobutton.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать на какой версии ОС у вас такое происходит. Но смело могу предположить, что дело в стилях, которые применяются в приложении.